# Why is my Makefile giving me problems?

Tags: function, class, makefile, header-files

I am supposed to write a Makefile that does "make all" to execute both testimage and testscene. But also if I wanted, I could do, make testscene or make testimage to compile only testimage. But why am I getting the errors,below, I have been around makefiles and this may mean that its not working.

```
EXENAME = testscene
OBJS = testscene.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o

EXENAME = testimage
OBJS = testimage.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o

CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -c -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LD = clang++
LDFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lpng -lc++abi

all : testimage testscene

$(EXENAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXENAME)

testscene: testscene.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o
    $(LD) testscene.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o $(LDFLAGS) -o testscene

testimage: testimage.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o
    $(LD) testimage.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o $(LDFLAGS) -o testimage

testscene.o : testscene.cpp scene.h image.h png.h rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) testscene.cpp

scene.o: scene.h image.h png.h rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) scene.cpp

testimage.o : testimage.cpp image.h png.h rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) testimage.cpp

image.o : image.cpp image.h png.h rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) image.cpp

png.o : png.cpp png.h rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) png.cpp

rgbapixel.o : rgbapixel.cpp rgbapixel.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) rgbapixel.cpp
clean :
    -rm -f *.o $(EXENAME)
```

```
2@linux-a1 mp2]$ vi Makefile
2@linux-a1 mp2]$ make
Makefile:21: warning: overriding commands for target `testimage'
Makefile:15: warning: ignoring old commands for target `testimage'
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
2@linux-a1 mp2]$
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really?  Have you looked at the two lines that make provides you in the error messages?

At line 15 you have a rule for `$(EXENAME) : $(OBJS)` where the `EXENAME` variable is set to `testimage` (overriding and making useless the previous setting of `EXENAME` in the first line).

Then at line 21 you have another rule for `testimage: testimage.o scene.o image.o png.o rgbapixel.o`.

Hence the error.

Comment: I'd upvote if you remove the "Really?" as it definitely comes across as condescending.

Comment: +1, and I think the "Really?" is appropriate-- the Question shows very little research effort. (This makefile is also highly redundant, but that can wait for another day.)

Comment: I removed the code below, does that fix it,                        $(EXENAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXENAME)